# Abel's Theorem, alternate proof

Tags: summation, power-series

I'm trying to solve:

> Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Prove that:
>   $$
> \lim_{r\to1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n.
> $$
>   Hint: Sum by parts.

In class, I have seen a proof that involves showing first (using summation by parts) that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^na_n$ is convergent for $r\in[0,1]$ rather than for $r\in[0,1)$ only, and then exploiting continuity to obtain the result.

My question: is there a more direct way, as the text would suggest, to use summation by parts in order to isolate the $r\to1^-$ limit from $N\to\infty$?
I tried both ways of performing partial summation:
$$
S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N r^n a_n = r^N \sum_{n=1}^Na_n+ (1-r)\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}r^n\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j\\
=a_N\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(a_n-a_{n+1})\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.
$$
Taking $N\to \infty$ first (as we have to...)
$$
S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty = (1-r) \sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n \sum_{j=1}^na_j\\
=\frac{1}{1-r}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-a_{n+1})(1-r^{n+1}).
$$
However, I appear to be left with nothing new...